# sscanf optional format specifier or parameter

Tags: c, scanf

I have a string that I want to parse using `sscanf` with optional parameter in it

```
char text1[] = "ATEC\rATECASA";
char text2[] = "ATEChehe\rATECASA";
char header[3];
char command[3];
char data[128];


int result = sscanf_s(text1, "%2s%2s%s\r", 
    header,
    command,
    data);

//actual output to data variable
//output text1, data = ATECASA
//output text2, data = hehe
```

You could see that for **text1**, my data variable is getting **ATECASA**, but I want an empty string or **""**, how can I do that?

I want to be able to parse the string of `ATEChehe\r` into 3 chunks

```
header = "AT";
command = "EC";
data = "hehe"
```

but i want to make the data parameter as an optional, if there is no string after ATEC and before \r, it should return an empty string

```
header = "AT";
command = "EC";
data = ""
```

Comment: replace `'\r'` with `'\0'`. then do it. (with clear data)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i cant do that you could see in text1 there are still char after \r

Comment: or `sscanf_s(text1, "%2s%2s%127[^\r]", 
    header, 3,
    command, 3,
    data, 128);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yup that is a another soluton, but i am not using windows compiler, this is firmware code

Comment: [n1570.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) **K.3.5.3.7 The sscanf_s function 4** --> **K.3.5.3.2 The fscanf_s function 4**

Comment: _The fscanf_s function is equivalent to fscanf except that the c, s, and [ conversion
specifiers apply to a pair of arguments (unless assignment suppression is indicated by a
*). The first of these arguments is the same as for fscanf. That argument is
immediately followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type
rsize_t and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by the first argument
of the pair._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%[]` syntax.
You have to initialize at least data to an empty string before the sscanf.

```
data[0] = 0;
int result = sscanf_s(text1, "%2s%2s%[^\r]\r", 
    header,
    command,
    data);
```

Comment: It means "all chars but \r".

Comment: and why do we need to init it to be 0?

Comment: because when there's no third chunk, sscanf will only fill the two first strings, returning 2 in `result`. Data won't be overwritten and you may find garbage in it.